# Why Constructor variable cannot be used

Tags: java

I want to using the variable that already set in constructor but it return null.

Here is my code:

```
public class ServerConfig {

    private String ServerDbUrl;
    static String ServerDbUsername;
    static String ServerDbPassword;
    static String ServerDbName;
    private XMLConfiguration config; 

    public void  ServerConfig () {
        try {
            config = new XMLConfiguration(getClass().getResource("/config.xml"));
            // config.setExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine());

            //assign value;
            ServerDbUrl = config.getString("database.url");
            ServerDbUsername = config.getString("database.username");
            ServerDbPassword = config.getString("database.password");
            ServerDbName = config.getString("database.name");              
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
       }
    }

    public String GetServerDbUrl() {
        //return ServerDbUrl;
        return config.getString("database.url");
    }
```

On the function `GetServerDbUrl()`, either i want to get the `ServerDbUrl` or the `config.getString()` it would return null or error stack.

I know this short of newbie question, but I hope this would help another newbie like me in the future. any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Side note: Suppose an exception is thrown within the constructor. What state does your instance have? Is that a *useful* state for it to have? (Catching exceptions in constructors and leaving an instance uninitialized or half-initialized is generally not a good idea.)

Comment: Side note 2: In Java, the *overwhelming* convention is that method names and instance field names start with a lowercase letter (`getServerDbUrl`, not `GetServerDbUrl`; `serverDbUsername`, not `ServerDbUsername`). You can do what you like in your code, but it makes it much easier for people to read your code and help you if you stick to the more common conventions.

Comment: thanks for your explanation for the Exception that new knowledge for me and for the naming convention too

Answer (score 12):

This is not a constructor, it's a regular method.

```
public void  ServerConfig ()
```

Therefore creating an instance of `ServerConfig` doesn't execute this method, and your instance variables remain uninitialized.

You should change the signature to :

```
public ServerConfig ()
```

A constructor doesn't have a return type.

Comment: Thanks always simple solution for newbie :)

Comment: Crikey, I always assumed doing that would give a compilation error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In Eclipse it gives a warning - `This method has a constructor name`.